# Converting list of list of Int32 values to list of list of int values

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, numpy-dtype

I have a list of lists which contain numpy int32 values. I would like to convert all of these int32 values to regular int. The reason is because as a part of my process these values are fed into a non max suppression function later on, which won't accept int32.

Below is what the structure of what my data looks like (in regular int form). I don't know how to make a test set for int32 values... Or else I would probably have this problem figured out.

List of list of ints

```
test_list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

Edit: Some screenshots to help understand what my data looks like.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's *regular int*? do you mean `np.array(test_list, dtype=int)`?

Comment: You can convert any numpy array into a python list (with 'python ints' inside) with `np.array.tolist()`

Comment: How was this list created?  As shown in the answers the best way to make a list from an array is to use `tolist`, which converts things all the way.  This partial conversion sounds suspicious, as though it were produced iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
In [167]: [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in test_list]
Out[167]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Yes, this does work and is native. Just a friendly observation to be aware of if efficiency is of concern: the iterative approach here is ~21x slower, than a numpy `.tolist()` conversion.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. This was new for me!

Answer (score 2):

Examples of a non-iterative conversion.

Use the following to keep the structure as an `ndarray`:

```
a.astype(int)

>>> array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Or even more simply, use this to convert the `ndarray` to a `list`:

```
a.tolist()

>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

#### Background:

You mention that your list is of `int32` values. As such, it's highly likely that the 'list' is actually a `numpy.ndarray`. Here is an example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], dtype=np.int32)

>>> array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

If this is the case, then converting the `ndarray` to a 'normal' `list` of `int` values is as simple as the two examples shown above.

Comment: a.astype produces a "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'". a.tolist() produces AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'.

Comment: Correct. A list does not have these attributes, only `numpy.ndarray`s do. This means your object is already a `list`, and therefore the dtype should already be `int`.  If this isn't the case, may I kindly ask you to update the question and show the exact list we're trying to convert?  Thanks.

Comment: How can I recreate the list for you? As I stated in the question I'm not sure how to make a list of lists of int32 values. I'm happy to do so but I don't know how to specify that.

Comment: Fair play - because (as far as I'm aware), it's not possible natively. As mentioned by @hpaulj, it makes us suspicious of *how* this list was constructed. Can you please dig into this and update the question accordingly?  I'm almost betting it is a `list` wrapper, around `ndarrays` in order to get an `int32` dtype. But without evidence ... I don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'll be able to answer that satisfactorily, but I'll post some images of the data from the variable explorer in spyder so you can see types and stuff and am happy to iterate with you all if you want more information.

Comment: Very interesting. Give this a try: `np.array(test_list).astype(int)`. Basically just wrap your list of lists in an `ndarray` constructor to use the `.astype(int)` function. I just tested this with `float` values and it worked fine. Worth a go. (Still very suspicious ... ) Aside: upvoted for the tricky question.

Comment: I believe that works as well, thanks for going back and forth with me.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad we got something working for you.  (Would appreciate an upvote and accept; but totally up to you.) Cheers mate.